# Find all the type casting in project

Tags: eclipse, search, casting

I just want to find all the type casting done in my project.could some one give me starting point for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Eclipse can do that.

I think that you could possibly use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) to do this sort of thing; e.g. by defining an rule based on an XPath that selects AST nodes that correspond to typecasts.

Comment: done with the class by extending AbstractJavaRule ,now i am not sure hwo to use this class

Comment: I'm just guessing, but if you've done it right you can probably just define a custom ruleset containing just your rule, run PMD on your source tree, and see all of the typecasts as "violations".